# I cannot create or open a Unit Test Project in Visual Studio 2012 RC

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I am consistently getting errors upon opening or creating a unit test project in Visual Studio 2012 RC. Where might I find answers on how to resolve this issue. I have tried multiple repair installations. I have tried uninstalling and re-installing. I have removed all but a handful of extensions that come with the product (NuGet). Any help either fixing this bug or finding out where I could get assistance would be welcome.

```
The 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Tips.TuipPackage.TuipPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.TuipPackage, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' package did not load correctly.

The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by examining the file 'C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ActivityLog.xml'.
```

I believe this is the relevant section from that file:

```
Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {52CBD135-1F97-2580-011F-C7CD052E44DE}

Begin package loadBegin package load {52CBD135-1F97-2580-011F-C7CD052E44DE}

ERROR SetSite failed for packageSetSite failed for package {52CBD135-1F97-2580-011F-C7CD052E44DE} 80070057 - E_INVALIDARG

ERROR End package loadEnd package load {52CBD135-1F97-2580-011F-C7CD052E44DE} 80070057 - E_INVALIDARG

Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {52CBD135-1F97-2580-011F-C7CD052E44DE}

Begin package loadBegin package load {52CBD135-1F97-2580-011F-C7CD052E44DE}

ERROR SetSite failed for packageSetSite failed for package {52CBD135-1F97-2580-011F-C7CD052E44DE} 80070057 - E_INVALIDARG

ERROR End package loadEnd package load {52CBD135-1F97-2580-011F-C7CD052E44DE} 80070057 - E_INVALIDARG
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I stopped getting the error message was to remove the following sections in the .sln file that looked similar to this:

```
ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
    SomeName.vsmdi = SomeName.vsmdi
    Local.testsettings = Local.testsettings
    TraceAndTestImpact.testsettings = TraceAndTestImpact.testsettings
EndProjectSection
```

and this:

```
GlobalSection(TestCaseManagementSettings) = postSolution
    CategoryFile = SomeName.vsmdi
EndGlobalSection
```

Comment: Possibly related, this also solved an error I was receiving that would result in a popup saying "A file or folder with the name 'xxxxx' already exists. Please give a unique name to the item you are adding, or delete the existing item first."

VS2012 Pro RTM, only had the second section in my .sln file.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem, i removed everything about visual studio from 2010 to 2012, reboot and reinstalled 2012 RC with all selection checked. And it works now.